# What book should I read to learn how to maintain a bike?

Tags: maintenance, book

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find good bicycle maintenance info?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/210/where-to-find-good-bicycle-maintenance-info)

What book should someone that can fix a puncture but who have never replaced bearings etc read to learn how to maintain a bike?

Comment: Pretty much answered here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/210/where-to-find-good-bicycle-maintenance-info/767

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Park Tool's [Big Blue Book of Bike Repair](http://www.parktool.com/products/detail.asp?cat=19&item=BBB-2). Plenty of pictures and good explanations. This book has made a number of things seem a lot less intimidating.

Comment: You might consider adding this to the [existing question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/210/where-to-find-good-bicycle-maintenance-info/767) on repair books. This is a good one!